# Node.js express can not get the css and js file

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

Here is my main.ts file
I can not get my css and js file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HNuh.png)

```
import express from 'express';
import {Request,Response} from 'express';
import expressSession from 'express-session';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();


// set session 
app.use(expressSession({
    resave:true,
    saveUninitialized:true
}));

// teach the server to go to the main page//
app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../frontend/public/index.html"));
});



app.use(express.static('public'))

const PORT = 8080;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${PORT}/`);
});
```

And here is my file structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlklJ.png)
here is my html file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlzH7.png)

Comment: `app.use(express.static('public'))` does not map onto the directory where the files live. Note that it will be relative to the current working directory when you run `node xxxxxxx.js`.

Comment: can you share the contents of index.html?

Comment: I posted the screenshoot on the post thx all

Answer (score -1):

First things first, you shouldn't post the app secret in a public forum. Second, can you post your index.html file? Chances are it incorrectly loads the JS and CSS files. Third, you can import default and class exports from a package in one line. Change

```
import express from 'express';
import {Request,Response} from 'express';
```

to

```
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
```

Answer (score -2):

seems from the screenshot that your public folder is empty. you seem to have the index.html and other files in your frontend folder and not in the public folder. your index.js and your index.html are on the same level. so your path does not resolve correctly if you resolve it from the index.js file

from which file are you resolving the path? from index.js or main.ts?

Comment: "seems from the screenshot that your public folder is empty. you seem to have the index.html and other files in your frontend folder and not in the public folder" — No. `frontend / public` means that `frontend` is empty *except* for the `public` directory (so the UI is collapsing them) and that all three files are in `public`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).